# Query array of embedded mongodb documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to query a mongodb document without luck. 
The following query works to get a user whose id is domainOwner and scope is clearcrimson.

```
db.getCollection("users").findOne( { "roles": { $elemMatch: {_id: "domainOwner", scope: "clearcrimson" } } }, {_id:1})
```

How can I modify the query to get a user whose one email id could be a@b.com, id is domainOwner and scope is clearcrimson?

**Document:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : "7Rc5q2o3Qnv7j2HuT", 
    "emails" : [
        {"address" : "a@b.com"},
        {"address" : "c@d.com"},
    ], 
    "roles" : [
        {"_id" : "domainOwner", "scope" : "clearcrimson"}, 
        {"_id" : "domainOwner", "scope" : "clearcrimson2"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: There is nothing new in the question which I can see. Overall you just want to the document which is having double conditions matched inside the array. The only difference is the **document fields** nothing more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.getCollection("users").findOne({ "roles": {$elemMatch: { "_id": "domainOwner", "scope": "clearcrimson"}}, "emails.address": "a@b.com" })
```

As you are using `$elemMatch` to match multiple conditions in a single object of the array, you can use simple **`arrayName.fieldName`** to match for a single condition, like I did with **"emails.address"** in query above.

You can use **`$`** (**positional operator** to project only matched object from array)

```
db.getCollection("users").findOne({ "roles": {$elemMatch: { "_id": "domainOwner", "scope": "clearcrimson"}}, "emails.address": "a@b.com" }, {_id: 1, "roles.$": 1, emails: 1})
```

We can not use two positional operators in one projection stage.
I am using mongo version 3.4.